# Hide a folder's state

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-sharing

When you file share a folder in Windows 7, it says "State: Shared" at the bottom; How can I remove that? When I enable file sharing I want it to look like it's not being file shared.

Comment: The only method I know is to stop sharing the folder

Comment: There has to be some way to disable this :/